# Can't get result with cvMatchTemplate?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I have two images of character "U".I compared their similarity using cvMatchTemplate function. Then, I used the cvMinMaxLoc
function to find the maximum and minimum values of pixels and their respective locations.
But when I compare them, it returns a maximum value with the character "Q" and maximum and minimum values are same. I dont understand what is the problem here???
Size of the images are same.
My code is:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    char text[]={'Q','U'};
       IplImage * tmp[2];       
       tmp[0]=cvLoadImage("D:\\Standards\\u.bmp",1);
       tmp[1]=cvLoadImage("D:\\Standards\\q.bmp",1);

       IplImage* src;
IplImage* dst;
IplImage* gray;
IplImage* grayThresh;
IplImage* gray1[1];
IplImage* grayThresh1[1];
int threshold = 120, maxValue = 255;
int thresholdType = CV_THRESH_BINARY;

src = cvLoadImage("D:\\OU.bmp", 1);
gray = cvCreateImage( cvSize(src->width,src->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
cvCvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
grayThresh = cvCloneImage( gray );
cvThreshold(gray, grayThresh, threshold, maxValue, thresholdType);

for(int i=0;i<=1;i++){
gray1[i] = cvCreateImage( cvSize(tmp[i]->width,tmp[i]->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
cvCvtColor(tmp[i], gray1[i], CV_BGR2GRAY );
grayThresh1[i] = cvCloneImage( gray1[i] );
cvThreshold(gray1[i], grayThresh1[i], threshold, maxValue, thresholdType);
}
CvPoint     minloc, maxloc;
       double       minval, maxval;

       int iwidth = grayThresh1[0]->width - grayThresh->width + 1;
       int iheight =grayThresh1[0]->height - grayThresh->height + 1;
       IplImage *res=cvCreateImage( cvSize(iwidth,iheight),32,1);

       for(int i=0;i<=1;i++){
     cvMatchTemplate(grayThresh,grayThresh1[i],res,CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
     cvMinMaxLoc( res, &minval, &maxval, &minloc, &maxloc, 0 );
     cout<<text[i]<<" maxval="<<maxval<<" minval="<<minval<<endl;}

cvDestroyWindow( "grayThresh" );
cvDestroyWindow( "src" );
cvDestroyWindow( "dst" );
cvDestroyWindow( "grayThresh1" );
cvReleaseImage( &src );     
cvReleaseImage( &grayThresh );
cvReleaseImage( &dst );
for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
cvReleaseImage( &grayThresh1[i] );
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting - it's pretty hard to read (and therefore hard to debug) in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
IplImage* gray1[1];
IplImage* grayThresh1[1];
```

to:

```
IplImage* gray1[2];
IplImage* grayThresh1[2];
```